# How do I change the unused background color in vim?

Tags: vim, highlight

How do you change the unused / bottom portion of the vim editor? The picture will hopefully clarify my terrible description :).

[image: vim editor screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That section is controlled by the highlight group NonText. So you can add the following line after your colorscheme line to set the background color to blue.

```
highlight NonText ctermbg=blue
```

Of course change blue to whatever color you want. Also if you are in gvim you will want to use `guibg=` to set the background color.