# Changing background colors

Tags: vim

Okay, I'm rather new to vim. I couldn't figure out how to change background colors. I'm editing my vimrc file to set these colors, but I couldn't find anything for background colors.

I'm using a color scheme and I just need to know how I could override it or what is to look for so I can change it in my colors/theme.vim file. I need to change two background colors. I point to them in the image attached.

[image: I need to change these two colors]

Comment: if you're using a vim colorscheme, you should have that colorscheme in your .vim folder, open the colorscheme file in vim and enjoy your changes. sorry I couldn't give you the specific field names, but at least you have a starting point

Comment: Is this related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117526/specifying-the-vim-background-colour)?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't really know how to change those colors. I'm getting all sorts of results when I make changes

Comment: you can use `colorscheme` and `set background` in vimrc

Comment: You may find [vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify) useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the unused background color in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818652/how-do-i-change-the-unused-background-color-in-vim)

Comment: Yep, looks like it was. Wish search had brought that up. The answer is `highlight NonText`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out the big blue section is controlled by `highlight NonText`

I added my .vimrc file to this:

`highlight NonText ctermfg=59 ctermbg=0 cterm=NONE guifg=#414e58 guibg=#232c31 gui=NONE`

and that gave me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

VIM has some color scheme, which store under `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/colors`, and it named as `desert.vim` for example.

you can simply add one line in your `vimrc` file, which should be locate in your `$HOME`, if there is NOT, you can create one, and add:

```
colorscheme desert
```

also some command you can use to set the background color like:

```
set background=light
```

or

```
set background=dark
```

I think for SSH, light is better:) If you use X windows, I suggest to use `bensday.vim`, it can be download from web