# Change foreground color in GVim

Tags: vim, text-editor, color-scheme

I want change this boring grey of my foreground but don't know the commands and the syntax.
I am using a theme that i took and customized my own from http://bytefluent.com/vivify/
The theme is: `adrian_modified`

Image: [image: the text editor running 'adrian_modified']

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the unused background color in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818652/how-do-i-change-the-unused-background-color-in-vim)

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094481/changing-background-colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:highlight NonText guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#00ff00`

Alter the colors to your liking. :)

Comment: For anyone using a terminal-based vim: ctermfg/ctermbg. You can also used named colours; see `help:cterm-colors`. There are also xtermfg/xtermfg and `xterm-colors` if you're in that environment.

Comment: I typed at Normal mode: `:highlight NonText guifg=#black guibg=black`and it changes perfectly at the moment with my adrian_modified.vim theme. But i put at the vimrc the same command without : but doesn't work when i restart GVim. What i need to do?

Comment: @AndréLuiz put the command in your vimrc after the colorscheme command. Or edit the colorscheme